# Why is Babel 7 not compiling node_modules files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have error in IE11 SCRIPT1002: Syntax error (problem with class syntax).
My simple code with 2 lines:

```
import { struct } from 'superstruct';
console.log('finished');
```

I wan't that my babel7 compile class into ES5 code

I have tried write .babelrc file :

```
 {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "ie": "11"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-classes haven't fixed too

**Update : 
  I have tried use @babel/plugin-preset-es2015 which convert class in ES5 code but this package is deprecated in babel7**

Help me please

Comment: do you have `@babel/core` also installed?

Comment: if you dont need you can exclude all node modules _except_ qs  or include for compile

Comment: "@babel/core": "^7.0.0   and {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules___(hardcode)____/
            }   but it didn't  help

Comment: Are you transpiling via babel directly, or using this with webpack?  If you run `babel input.js > output.js` can you post the output with your configuration above? (babel-cli)  (aside, so happy I don't have to support IE anymore at work)

Comment: Have you tried the next version of [@babel/plugin-transform-classes](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-classes.html), can you provide your attempt at using this.

Comment: I think targets should not be there.

Comment: @zloctb I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation of how to solve this with webpack and babel.config.js. Let us know if you're using something else!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to transform node_modules and child packages in Babel 7 you need to use a `babel.config.js` file instead of a `.babelrc` file.

See this [issue comment](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/149#issuecomment-417895085) and the babel documentation on [project-wide configuration](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#project-wide-configuration). Specifically

> New in Babel 7.x, Babel has as concept of a "root" directory, which defaults to the current working directory. For project-wide configuration, Babel will automatically search for a "babel.config.js" in this root directory.
>
> ...
>
> Because project-wide config files are separated from the physical location of the config file, they can be ideal for configuration that must apply broadly, even allowing plugins and presets to easily apply to files in node_modules or in symlinked packages, which were traditionally quite painful to configure in Babel 6.x.

The short of it is that `.babelrc` is used for a local project file transformations (not including `node_modules`) while `babel.config.js` should be considered project-wide and will apply to package dependencies when bundling (`node_modules`). It's a bit confusing but hopefully that helps!

#### Edit

Here's a bit more information on a full project config to build your example file using webpack. Note that if you use `.babelrc` instead of `babel.config.js` here it *will not work.* Running `webpack-cli` produces a script `script.out.js` that does not use the class keyword.

script.js

```
import { struct } from 'superstruct';
console.log('finished');
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                    "targets": {
                    "ie": "11"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './script.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'script.out.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [ {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        } ]
    }
}
```

Package Dependencies

```
"@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
"superstruct": "^0.6.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
```

Comment: Hi can u give some workoing NodeJS code on how to exactly do this? Simply runnign ransform isnt working: babel.transform

Comment: This new behaviour is really stupid. It means dependencies can no longer tell their parent projects how to transpile them, which encourages library authors to ship ES5 instead of source. It's a gigantic step backwards.

Comment: How's that a step backward? What do you need to specify how it should be transpiled? I am intrigued. The consuming application knows best what they need to target and be control how your lib should be transpiled. An I missing something?