# How to get webpack to apply babel presets on resolved subproject sources?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have a weback config that compiles source files in ./src

Some files in my project must import functions from a subproject in ./subproject/src

I use the resolve option in the webpack config:

```
 resolve: {alias: {subproject: path.resolve(__dirname, "subproject/src")},},
```

which allows me to import functions from the subproject with:

```
import {myFunc} from "subproject/funcs/myFunc"
```

The resolving and importing works fine, but I have JSX syntax in the imported files, and the babel transformation are not being applied to imported files.

So I get this error:

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

My babel config (.babelrc):

```
 { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]}
```

So the preset-react is only transforming code in ./src, but not to the code in ./subproject/src

Here is the relevant part of the webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  resolve: {alias: {subproject: path.resolve(__dirname, "subproject/src")},},
```

Comment: Is your Babel config a `.babelrc` or a `babel.config.js`?

Comment: I tried both, as per suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788809/why-is-babel-7-not-compiling-node-modules-files  it didn't work

Comment: Then most likely the file isn't being detected or isn't exporting the config properly. I'd recommend starting by reading over https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files